# Mobile browsers not working with Jquery mousedown/touchstart/HTML5 Canvas UI element

Tags: jquery, html, animation, mobile

So I've been trying to spend hours on getting this UI toggle switch to work on mobile and I sort of have it, but not ideally.

If you use it on a desktop browser you will find that you are able to both click on the "on" or "off" side of the toggle switch and it will switch to that side and it is also "draggable".

In the Android mobile browser and Chrome for Android you still can click and release the toggle switch and get it on the side you want, however you lose the "dragging" function. I think it may be an issue with how the animation is rendering or something. Here is the code the event handler of my script:

```
$("#"+togID).on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
    mouseIsDown=true;
    animate();
});
$(document).on('mouseup', function() {
  if(mouseIsDown){
    animate();
    if(on===true){
    primXX=cw-cx;
    draw();
    } else {
    primXX=cx;
    }
  mouseIsDown=false;
}
});
}
```

**Other info:** Here is a link to the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Doug021786/w5t0d5qg/2/)** and it should be noted that I'm using the jquery 1.11.X library and [Paul Irish's rAF polyfill](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/paulirish/1579671/raw/682e5c880c92b445650c4880a6bf9f3897ec1c5b/rAF.js)

Any help is greatly appreciated!